# GitLab CI: YAML not being run

Tags: gitlab, yaml

I am getting the following error from GitLab when I committed:

```
(<unknown>): did not find expected '-' indicator while parsing a block collection at line 29 column 5
```

The file did not change between commits but somehow is failing now, when it succeeded in the past.

**.gitlab-ci.yaml**

```
image: 'ubuntu:latest'

stages:
  - test
  - pages

before_script:
  - apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y
  - apt-get install -y python3.7 python3-pip xvfb qt5-default

test:
  stage: test
  except:
    changes:
      - CHANGELOG.txt
      - README.RST
      - requirements.txt
      - tools
      - LICENSE
      - example.py
      - setup.py
  script:
    - python3.7 -m pip install pyqt5 pytest pytest-qt pytest-cov
    - python3.7 setup.py install
    - xvfb-run python3.7 -m pytest --cov=NodalPy tests/

pages:
  script:
    - python3.7 -m pip install sphinx sphinx-rtd-theme
    - sphinx-build docs/source docs/build
    - mkdir public
    - sphinx-build docs/source docs/build
    - mv docs/build/ public/
    artifacts:
      paths:
        - public
  only:
    - master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`artifacts` indentation is not correct, must be at the same level than `script`

```
pages:
script:
  - python3.7 -m pip install sphinx sphinx-rtd-theme
  - sphinx-build docs/source docs/build
  - mkdir public
  - sphinx-build docs/source docs/build
  - mv docs/build/ public/
artifacts:
  paths:
    - public
only:
- master
```